# How to write automated unit tests for java annotation processor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm experimenting with java annotation processors. I'm able to write integration tests using the "JavaCompiler" (in fact I'm using "hickory" at the moment). I can run the compile process and analyse the output. The Problem: a single test runs for about half a second even without any code in my annotation processor. This is way too long to using it in TDD style.

Mocking away the dependencies seems very hard for me (I would have to mock out the entire "javax.lang.model.element" package). Have someone succeed to write unit tests for an annotation processor (Java 6)? If not ... what would be your approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right mocking the annotation processing API (with a mock library like easymock) is painful. I tried this approach and it broke down pretty rapidly. You have to setup to many method call expectations. The tests become unmaintainable.

A **state-based test approach** worked for me reasonably well. I had to implement the parts of the [javax.lang.model.* API I needed for my tests](https://bitbucket.org/blob79/quickcheck/src/c8e12cc026fd6295966bf9ff5d20919961ff4149/quickcheck-src-generator/src/test/java/net/java/quickcheck/srcgenerator/Model.java?at=default). (That were only < 350 lines of code.)

This is the part of a test to initiate the javax.lang.model objects. After the setup the model should be in the same state as the Java compiler implementation.

```
DeclaredType typeArgument = declaredType(classElement("returnTypeName"));
DeclaredType validReturnType = declaredType(interfaceElement(GENERATOR_TYPE_NAME), typeArgument);
TypeParameterElement typeParameter = typeParameterElement();
ExecutableElement methodExecutableElement = Model.methodExecutableElement(name, validReturnType, typeParameter);
```

The static factory methods are defined in the class `Model` implementing the javax.lang.model.* classes. For example `declaredType`. (All unsupported operations will throw exceptions.)

```
public static DeclaredType declaredType(final Element element, final TypeMirror... argumentTypes) {
    return new DeclaredType(){
        @Override public Element asElement() {
            return element;
        }
        @Override public List<? extends TypeMirror> getTypeArguments() {
            return Arrays.asList(argumentTypes);
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return format("DeclareTypeModel[element=%s, argumentTypes=%s]",
                    element, Arrays.toString(argumentTypes));
        }
        @Override public <R, P> R accept(TypeVisitor<R, P> v, P p) {
            return v.visitDeclared(this, p);
        }
        @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        @Override public int hashCode() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

        @Override public TypeKind getKind() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        @Override public TypeMirror getEnclosingType() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    };
}
```

The rest of the test verifies the behavior of the class under test.

```
Method actual = new Method(environment(), methodExecutableElement);
Method expected = new Method(..);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

You can have a look at the [source code of the Quickcheck @Samples and @Iterables source code generator tests](https://bitbucket.org/blob79/quickcheck/src/c8e12cc026fd6295966bf9ff5d20919961ff4149/quickcheck-src-generator/src/test/java/net/java/quickcheck/srcgenerator?at=default). (The code is not optimal, yet. The Method class has to many parameters and the Parameter class is not tested in its own test but as part of the Method test. It should illustrate the approach nevertheless.)

Viel Glück!

Answer (score 62):

This is an old question, but it seems that the state of annotation processor testing hadn't gotten any better, so we released [Compile Testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing) today.  The best docs are in [package-info.java](https://github.com/google/compile-testing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/testing/compile/package-info.java), but the general idea is that there is a fluent API for testing compilation output when run with an annotation processor.  For example,

```
ASSERT.about(javaSource())
    .that(JavaFileObjects.forResource("HelloWorld.java"))
    .processedWith(new MyAnnotationProcessor())
    .compilesWithoutError()
    .and().generatesSources(JavaFileObjects.forResource("GeneratedHelloWorld.java"));
```

tests that the processor generates a file that matches `GeneratedHelloWorld.java` (golden file on the class path).  You can also test that the processor produces error output:

```
JavaFileObject fileObject = JavaFileObjects.forResource("HelloWorld.java");
ASSERT.about(javaSource())
    .that(fileObject)
    .processedWith(new NoHelloWorld())
    .failsToCompile()
    .withErrorContaining("No types named HelloWorld!").in(fileObject).onLine(23).atColumn(5);
```

This is obviously a lot simpler than mocking and unlike typical integration tests, all of the output is stored in memory.

Comment: Wow, this is a great little library! The [examples](https://github.com/google/compile-testing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/testing/compile/package-info.java) are a bit different now and use `Compilation` and `assertThat` instead of the syntax above. It took me a while to figure out that `assertThat` wasn't referring to AssertJ's `assertThat`, but a static import from the library itself.

Answer (score 5):

jOOR is a small Java reflection library that also provides simplified access to the in-memory Java compilation API in `javax.tool.JavaCompiler`. We added support for this to unit test [jOOQ's annotation processors](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/05/09/jsr-308-and-the-checker-framework-add-even-more-typesafety-to-jooq-3-9/). You can easily write unit tests like this:

```java
@Test
public void testCompileWithAnnotationProcessors() {
    AProcessor p = new AProcessor();

    try {
        Reflect.compile(
            "org.joor.test.FailAnnotationProcessing",
            "package org.joor.test; " +
            "@A " +
            "public class FailAnnotationProcessing { " +
            "}",
            new CompileOptions().processors(p)
        ).create().get();
        Assert.fail();
    }
    catch (ReflectException expected) {
        assertFalse(p.processed);
    }
}
```

[The above example has been taken from this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/12/07/how-to-unit-test-your-annotation-processor-using-joor/)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation, so I created the [Avatar](https://github.com/MatthewTamlin/Avatar) library. It won't give you the performance of a pure unit test with no compilation, but if used correctly you shouldn't see much of a performance hit.

Avatar lets you write a source file, annotate it, and convert it to elements in a unit test. This allows you to unit test methods and classes which consume Element objects, without manually invoking javac.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem awhile ago and found this question. Although the other answers provided are decent, I felt that that there was still room for improvement. Based on the other answers for this question, I created [Elementary](https://github.com/Pante/elementary), a suite of JUnit 5 extensions that provide a real annotation processing environment for unit tests.

Most libraries test annotation processors by running them. However, most annotation processors are pretty complex and broken into more fine-grained components. It is not feasible to test individual components by running the annotation processor. Instead, we make the annotation processing environment available to these tests.

The following code snippet illustrates how to test a `Lint` component:

```java
import com.karuslabs.elementary.junit.Cases;
import com.karuslabs.elementary.junit.Tools;
import com.karuslabs.elementary.junit.ToolsExtension;
import com.karuslabs.elementary.junit.annotations.Case;
import com.karuslabs.elementary.junit.annotations.Introspect;
import com.karuslabs.utilitary.type.TypeMirrors;

@ExtendWith(ToolsExtension.class)
@Introspect
class ToolsExtensionExampleTest {

    Lint lint = new Lint(Tools.typeMirrors());
    
    @Test
    void lint_string_variable(Cases cases) {
        var first = cases.one("first");
        assertTrue(lint.lint(first));
    }
    
    @Test
    void lint_method_that_returns_string(Cases cases) {
        var second = cases.get(1);
        assertFalse(lint.lint(second));
    }
    
    @Case("first") String first;
    @Case String second() { return "";}
    
}

class Lint {
    
    final TypeMirrors types;
    final TypeMirror expectedType;
    
    Lint(TypeMirrors types) {
        this.types = types;
        this.expectedType = types.type(String.class);
    }
    
    public boolean lint(Element element) {
        if (!(element instanceof VariableElement)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        var variable = (VariableElement) element;
        return types.isSameType(expectedType, variable.asType());
    }
    
}
```

By annotating the test class with `@Introspect` and test cases with `@Case`, we can declare test cases in the same file as the tests. The corresponding `Element` representation of the test cases can be retrieved by a test using `Cases`.

If anyone is interested, I wrote an article, [The Problem with Annotation Processors](https://dzone.com/articles/the-problem-with-annotation-processors) that details the problems with unit testing annotation processors.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to bundle all tests in one class. Half a second for compiling etc. is then a constant for a given set of tests, the real test time for a test is negligible, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/raw-file/default/openide.util.lookup/test/unit/src/org/openide/util/test/AnnotationProcessorTestUtils.java though this is based on `java.io.File` for simplicity and so has the performance overhead you complain about.

Thomas's suggestion of mocking the whole JSR 269 environment would lead to a pure unit test. You might instead want to write more of an integration test which checks how your processor actually runs inside javac, giving more assurance it is correct, but merely want to avoid disk files. Doing this would require you to write a mock `JavaFileManager`, which is unfortunately not as easy as it seems and I have no examples handy, but you should not need to mock other things like `Element` interfaces.